# What is causing this error? Missing scheme in request url: h

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

When I am trying to crawl my webpage it is giving me the output but some error is showing up:

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
```

books2.py

```
class Books1Spider(Spider):
    name = 'books1'

    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']
    headers = {
            "Host": "localhost",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
            "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8"
        } 


    def parse_book(self,response):
        title = response.xpath('//h1/text()').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('.//*[@class="price_color"]/text()').extract_first()

        image_urls = response.xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first()
        image_urls = image_urls.replace('../..','http://books.toscrape.com/')


        rating = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"star-rating")]/@class').extract_first()
        rating = rating.replace('star-rating','')

        description = response.xpath('//*[@id="product_description"]/following-sibling::p/text()').extract_first()

yield { 'title':title,
        'price':price,
        'image_urls':image_urls,
        'rating':rating,
        'description': description,
        }
```

Expected result:

```
{'rating': u' Five', 'price': u'\xa352.29', 'description': u'Scott Pilgrim\'s life is totally sweet. He\'s 23 years old, he\'s in a rockband, he\'s "between jobs" and he\'s dating a cute high school girl. Nothing could possibly go wrong, unless a seriously mind-blowing, dangerously fashionable, rollerblading delivery girl named Ramona Flowers starts cruising through his dreams and sailing by him at parties. Will Scott\'s awesome life get Scott Pilgrim\'s life is totally sweet. He\'s 23 years old, he\'s in a rockband, he\'s "between jobs" and he\'s dating a cute high school girl. Nothing could possibly go wrong, unless a seriously mind-blowing, dangerously fashionable, rollerblading delivery girl named Ramona Flowers starts cruising through his dreams and sailing by him at parties. Will Scott\'s awesome life get turned upside-down? Will he have to face Ramona\'s seven evil ex-boyfriends in battle? The short answer is yes. The long answer is Scott Pilgrim, Volume 1: Scott Pilgrim\'s Precious Little Life ...more', 'image_urls': u'http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/97/27/97275841c81e66d53bf9313cba06f23e.jpg', 'title': u"Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)"}
```

The actual result is:

```
2019-02-07 16:06:54 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'rating': u' Five', 'price': u'\xa352.29', 'description': u'Scott Pilgrim\'s life is totally sweet. He\'s 23 years old, he\'s in a rockband, he\'s "between jobs" and he\'s dating a cute high school girl. Nothing could possibly go wrong, unless a seriously mind-blowing, dangerously fashionable, rollerblading delivery girl named Ramona Flowers starts cruising through his dreams and sailing by him at parties. Will Scott\'s awesome life get Scott Pilgrim\'s life is totally sweet. He\'s 23 years old, he\'s in a rockband, he\'s "between jobs" and he\'s dating a cute high school girl. Nothing could possibly go wrong, unless a seriously mind-blowing, dangerously fashionable, rollerblading delivery girl named Ramona Flowers starts cruising through his dreams and sailing by him at parties. Will Scott\'s awesome life get turned upside-down? Will he have to face Ramona\'s seven evil ex-boyfriends in battle? The short answer is yes. The long answer is Scott Pilgrim, Volume 1: Scott Pilgrim\'s Precious Little Life ...more', 'image_urls': u'http://books.toscrape.com//media/cache/97/27/97275841c81e66d53bf9313cba06f23e.jpg', 'title': u"Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/divum/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/divum/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/media.py", line 79, in process_item
    requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
  File "/home/divum/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/pipelines/images.py", line 155, in get_media_requests
    return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, [])]
  File "/home/divum/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
 File "/home/divum/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py", line 62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
```

Comment: please give to us your code (where is for x in item.get(self.images_urls_field, []))

Answer (score 2):

You are extracting `image_urls` as `u'…'`. The value of `image_urls` must be a list: `[u'…']`.

In your code, switch:

```py
image_urls = response.xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first()
image_urls = image_urls.replace('../..','http://books.toscrape.com/')
```

to

```
image_url = response.xpath('.//img/@src').extract_first()
image_urls = [image_url.replace('../..','http://books.toscrape.com/')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like you are missing or passing some invalid details in Request call.

Go to your all Request and find out that the url you are passing is in correct form.

Try using `Request(response.urljoin(url), ...)` So that it will cover any bad url schema.